# Обновление ViewPager при листании

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

ViewPager имеет 5 страниц (которые я хочу затем использовать повторно), соответсвующий PagerAdapter имеет массив с вьюшками, я заполняю его при старте программы и затем показываю центральную страницу:

```
0 1 |2| 3 4
```

Теперь при листании я использую страницу с противоположного конца массива, обновляя ее новыми данными (на основе календарных дат), в зависимости от направления листания:

```
повторное использование:
4 0 |1| 2 3 или 
1 2 |3| 4 0 и тд
```

Обновляю страницы в `onPageSelected` из `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`, но при этом при листании в анимации происходит задержка из-за довольно медленного кода при обновлении страницы (код не ускорить).

Поэтому я вынес медленный код в отдельный поток и обновляю затем страницы с помощью метода `post` вьюшек. Работать стало быстрее, но все равно подтормаживает.

Вопрос - как можно оптимизировать/переписать такой алгоритм?

**Обновление**

Вопрос еще вот в чем. Как я и написал, выполнение кода вынес в поток, но все равно подтормаживает из-за большого количества вьюшек на странице видимо из-за вызова `post`, попробовал сделать все в потоке от начала до конца - от инфлейта до заполнения вьюшек, но проблема возникла при попытке подсунуть созданную так страницу в `PagerAdapter` и вызвать затем `notifyDataSetChanged()` - после этого вылетает

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Может быть, это из-за того, что я в качестве `rootView` передаю созданный в главном потоке `ViewPager`?

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_calendar, mViewPager, false);
```

**Обновление 2**

Вроде разобрался и с этим, запощу ответ

Comment: Подгружать 9 страниц, например. 5 отображаемых, по 2 справа и слева. При достижении страницы 1 или 5 начинать подгрузку 2-х страниц справа или слева. Подгруженные страницы чистить не сразу: оставлять два набора по 5 страниц (т.е. до 10 страниц висит в памяти. Удаляются самые старые по дате, дату обновлять по времени обращения к странице).

Comment: Отображается всего одна из пяти, центральная.

Comment: Отображается 1, справа и слева по 2, дополнительно, чтобы заполнить буфер из листаемых (те, что по 2 справа и слева) - ещё по 2. Чтобы был запас страниц для отоброажения и запас страниц для пополнения "очереди на отображение" - тех самых страниц справа и слева от центрального элемента. Если выбирают сразу крайний элемент - у нас уже готовы два на заполнение будущих двух крайних. И мы уже грузим следующие два про запас. При этом следим, чтобы с противоположной стороны вовремя освободилось место (ресурсы).

Comment: @DimXenon, обновил вопрос

Comment: Таки ждем ответ!)

Comment: @whalemare, я помню, но ещё не до конца все закодил как надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За неимением достаточного времени на разъяснения оставлю здесь ссылку на копипасту готового кода из проекта, все же лучше чем ничего. Кто желает обсудить/довести до ума в плане портабельности
[милости просим](https://github.com/schmidt9/ContentViewPager-Android)